# Stop currently running HTTP Post operation on popViewController

Tags: ios

The following code is used to make a `post` request to a server using `AFHTTPClient`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        //objects and keys
                        nil];

[httpClient postPath:postPath parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

   id results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

    //completion block

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];
[httpClient release];
```

But I noticed the request is still running even when the user has popped from the current `viewController` (noticed when a timed out error was logged, when on another `viewController`).

How do stop the request, when the `viewController` is no longer in the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
[[httpClient operationQueue] cancelAllOperations];
```

or this :

```
[self cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/path"];
```

You can put one of them in your `viewWillDisappear`;